# Как сделать сайт адаптивным только при разрешении меньше 768px?

Tags: jquery

На сайте прописан

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000">
```

Как сделать сайт адаптивным при разрешении меньше 768 px? Чтобы при разрешении меньше 768 px прописывался

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При первой загрузке сайта, и при изменении размера окна - проверяете ширину окна браузера, и меняете содержимое вашего существующего meta-тега:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var reinitMeta = function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
      $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0');
    } else {
      $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'width=1000');
    }
  };
  reinitMeta();
  $(window).resize(reinitMeta);
});
```